# JQuery Fancybox Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I've recently started learning JQuery, and I'm doing fine with it. Though, I'm using [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net)
and I'm having some trouble.

I want to display a form inside a `<div>` rather than an iframe. I'm not sure how to display a 
`<div style="display: hidden;">` with FancyBox.

http://jsfiddle.net/nLcMh/21/

I have the form inside a hidden div tag and I want to use FancyBox to display it. Fancybox is a type of JQuery lighbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you need something with more options try this fiddle:

```
$("a.openform").click(function () {
        $.fancybox(
                $('.form').html(),
                {
                    'width'             : 950,
                    'height'            : 1100,
                    'autoScale'         : false,
                    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                    'hideOnContentClick': false,
                    'onStart': function () {
                      //On Start callback if needed  
                    }
                 }
            );
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RQQ5r/1/

Comment: Thanks, but the form is still not displaying. I'm using Safari IOS right now. I'm trying to make it so Fancybox displays my form inside its light box. [Number_5](http://fancybox.net/blog) I'm not sure how they do this, though.

Comment: It's working now. Thanks. I didn't realize that I was calling FancyBox wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nLcMh/28/
Changed link to `<a href="#form" class="openform">See Form</a>`